# Convergent of Divergent of sequence having Rational terms

Tags: convergence-divergence

> Finding whether the sequence
>
> $$a_{n}=\sqrt{1+n}\sqrt{2-n}-\bigg(\sqrt{1+n}\bigg)^2+2n+1$$ is convergent or Divergent.
>
> If convergent, Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{n}$ equals

What i try:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\bigg[\sqrt{n+1}\bigg(\sqrt{n-2}-\sqrt{n+1}\bigg)\bigg]+2n+1$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}-\frac{3\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n-2}+\sqrt{n+1}}+2n+1$$

How i find that limits, please Help me Thanks

$\color{Blue}{\text{Edited::}}$

Instead of $\sqrt{n-2}$ actually it is $\sqrt{2-n}$

$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\bigg[\sqrt{n+1}\bigg(\sqrt{2-n}-\sqrt{n+1}\bigg)\bigg]+2n+1$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}(1-2n)}{\sqrt{2-n}+\sqrt{n+1}}+2n+1$$

Comment: With $\sqrt{2-n}$, what is $a_3$ beside a complex number ? Is the sequance supposed to be complex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sqrt {2-n}$ must be a typo since it is defined (as a real number) only when $n \leq 2$. So. I will take it as $\sqrt {n-2}$

This is of the form $b_n+2n+1$ where $b_n \to -\frac 3  2$ (as seen by dividing numerator and denominator by $\sqrt n$). Hence the limit is $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks Professor .So can we say that the sequence is Diverges as limit of sequence goes to infinity.

Comment: @jacky That is correct.

Comment: Professor please have a look on that problem. I have done calculation mistake insteat of $\sqrt{n-2}$ it is $\sqrt{2-n}$. Thanks

Comment: $\sqrt {2-n}$ is defined only when $n=1$ or $2$. So I thought you had typed $2-n$ in stead of $n-2$. @jacky